# Show irreducibility of markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I need to show that the markov chain that has transition matrix written below is irreducible.
\begin{bmatrix} 
 0.2     & 0.5     & 0.1  & 0.1     & 0.1  \\
 0.2     & 0.5     & 0.3  & 0     & 0  \\
 0.2     & 0     & 0.4  & 0.4     & 0  \\
 0.2     & 0     & 0.2  & 0.4     & 0.2  \\
 0.2     & 0     & 0  & 0.1     & 0.7
\end{bmatrix}

Is it enough for me to say for $n = 1,2,3,4,5$ we have that $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = n | X_0 =1) > 0$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1 | X_0 =n) > 0$?  Hence its irreducible. Is there any other (easier) way to show irreducibility?

Also, to calculate the stationary distribution, is the fastest/most convenient way to use $\pi P = \pi$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about irreducibility.

You usually find the invariant measure using $\pi=\pi P$ and linear algebra.
The invariant probability $\pi$ will be unique, since your chain is irreducible.

But your transition matrix is special, so there is a shortcut. The  column sums
of $P$ are all equal to one.
Such a transition  matrix is called *doubly stochastic* and its unique invariant probability 
measure is uniform, i.e., $\pi=\left({1\over 5},{1\over 5},{1\over 5},{1\over 5},{1\over 5}\right).$

Comment: Thanks @ByronSchmuland ! Didn't realise that trick for doubly stochastic matrices, thanks for that. May I ask, is there any other way to show irreducibility apart from what I did above?

Comment: @Richard Well, it amounts to the same thing, but you could calculate $P^2$ and note that all its entries are strictly positive.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks. Just curious to see if there was any other way, but I think I'll stay with what I did. :)